# AWS Postgres - max pid?

Tags: postgresql

Not sure what sort of platform AWS runs 9.x Postgres on. What's the maximum value for the process pid?

Im looking into an issue around the use of `pg_backend_pid` in a trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS doesn't run PostgreSQL.

- They run [Amazon Relational Database Service (RDS)](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/), based on PostgreSQL
- You can run PostgreSQL yourself on EC2, using something like the [Ubuntu Cloud images.](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/locator/ec2/)

> What's the maximum value for the process pid? Im looking into an issue around the use of pg_backend_pid in a trigger.

I assume the maximum value for process pid is the [maximum pid value for Linux.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6294133/124486)

But, for PostgreSQL it's stored in an interger.

```
select pg_typeof(pg_backend_pid());
 pg_typeof 
-----------
 integer
(1 row)
```

Which means the max value is `pow(2,31)-1`

Comment: With a little empirical testing it appears the max pid is 32767.  Used `SELECT pid FROM pg_stat_activity order by pid;`

Comment: Not sure why this q/a pair got downvoted. Tough crowd.